# Vue.js proxie api on with different/dynamic ports

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuetify.js

I made an app that uses the rest api of a server, which starts different instances on different ports. I'm currently using the devserver proxy to access the master api, but I couldn't figure out how to access different ports with the same path.

Current vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"],
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:10000',
  },
};
```

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
{
    '/world': {
      target: 'http://localhost:10001',
      pathRewrite: {'^/world/': '/world/'},
    },
    '/world': {
      target: 'http://localhost:10002',
      pathRewrite: {'^/world/': '/world/'},
    }
  }
```